# Search Box to Search Text on Current PAge

Tags: search

Is it possible to add a search box to a specific page and search for ONLY the text on that page?

If so, any pointers would be helpful. Is there a module for this?

Thanks

Comment: What result do you anticipate to happen with this search box that only searches that one page?  Are you expecting anything different other than what a Ctrl+f on a browser would do?  Because I know you can do a search filter on a view that displays a single node, but it would be silly because you're only searching a single entry that's already there....

Comment: Seems better suited for stackoverflow.com where it's already answered: [JQuery search in static HTML page with highlighting of found word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word)

Comment: The page has a large table that I would like users to be able to search.